# PHP socket_sendto cannot connect to any host

Tags: php, apache, sockets

I am working on writing up a script that collects some metrics, and sends an abridged version to another server; I am using the folowing:

```
<?php

$statsHost="stats0";
$statsPort=2003;

...

$size = strlen( $packet );
echo "The packet is [ " . $size . "b ].";

$sock = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );

socket_sendto( $sock, $packet, $size, 0, $statsHost, $statsPort);

socket_close( $sock );
```

Even with [the most basic socketing example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php), I can not establish a successful connection to the server:

> PHP Warning:  socket_sendto(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in stats.php on line 37

Broken pipe usually indicates an issue with the server side - which appears to be working as expected, both or the following have no issues connecting to the server, as do none of the existing client connections.

```
echo "a.b 1 1" | nc $statsHost $statsPort
# and
telnet $statsHost $statsPort
```

Might there be some php / httpd configuration issue that is preventing me from doing this?

SELinux is disabled; firewalld is disabled, I have tried using IP address instead of hostnames, and I have tried connecting to local ports, all with the same issue.

PHP Version Info

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: im not seeing a socket_connect in your code neither a create_non_block some good examples on php.net page. http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php

Comment: From the docs - `socket_sendto — Sends a message to a socket, whether it is connected or not` - [Source w/ Example on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php)

Comment: There is an example on the page i linked with error checking which might help trace the problem.

Comment: Whelp, if you add that as an answer I will accept it, because it works. Following the example on the `socket_sendto` page, I could not make it work. This now works as expected.

Comment: All I did was point you in the right direction, You are able to write the answer yourself and mark it accepted. Glad i could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2154871/chris) for pointing me in the right direction here.

I am not sure if this is an issue with the PHP version that I am running, but

The [documentation claims that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php)

> Sends a message to a socket, whether it is connected or not

This appears to be false.

To make this work properly, I have to make an explicit call to

```
// need to call
socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);

// or else this will throw broken pipe
socket_sendto( $sock, $packet, $size, 0, $host, $port);
```